# Multiples passwords with keychain swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, keychain

I need to store multiples passwords because I can have multiples users in my app. I'm using KeychainWrapper.h and KeychainWrapper.m from [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/92667/securing-ios-data-keychain-touch-id-1password) and I've look a lot for a solution but I always get a answer to use some framework such as https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper or https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess, but I don't want to use any third part framework to achieve this.

I could only successfuly store data with keys like this:
kSecClass, kSecAttrService, kSecAttrAccount...

```
KeychainWrapper().mySetObject("myPassword", forKey: kSecAttrAccount)
```

How can I save passwords with custom keys for each user in my app? I don't know how many user will be logged in. When I use a string for the Key my app crashs.

Thank you in advance. have a nice day.

Comment: I understand that you don't want to use a 3rd party framework, but look at my code here https://github.com/ashleymills/Keychain.swift, and see how I store a value for a key. They key could be anything… `"passwordFor\(userId)"`, for example

Comment: Thank you  very much! It helped a lot!